# How can i get Input Keyevent return value?

Tags: android, android-activity, adb, keyevent

How can i know if **input key-event command** succeeded or not?

Like if i run `adb shell input keyevent 3` how can i know that it succeed?
I tried to write this command and look in **dmesg** and **logcat** logs but there no indication about it.

Comment: have you checked `adb shell getevent` while you enter the command ?

Comment: can you please be specific

Comment: like if i send command `adb shell input keyevent 3` (it can be another number) how i know that it succeed ?
How exactly `adb shell getevent` help here?

Comment: what i meant was, `getevent` is supposed to show all events happening from input devices. so when you press home button or any other key check corresponding event is reflecting in `adb shell getevent -lt` . I haven't tried this(for keyevent commands) though. But i tried getevent events for real screen touches. It works.

Comment: please enlighten us on your criteria of the command's success

Comment: @Rilwan, `sendevent` injects the event into the kernel event queue, `input` injects the event into the Android framework event queue - you won't those in `getevent` output

Comment: @Alex. Thanks for the insight. I thought framework interprets the input command and pass to below kernel as corresponding (sendevent) events. I think i need to learn more :D